# How to create and where to run a daily job to copy production database from Linode to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, linode

For historical reasons Heroku is where are reporting database is located, which is a direct copy of production from Linode.

I currently run commands locally every day to copy the Linode database from Linode server to local drive and then push it to Heroku. I need to automate this somehow so it runs 'somewhere' every day - but where?

I know about cron jobs etc and also that you can run workers on Heroku, but I really don't know what is the best/recommended way to go about this and would like to see what others recommend.

I tried googling but cannot seem to find anything that points me in the right direction - the results are always heroku to heroku copying! Perhaps someone on here knows of some tools/services that might help automate this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing is to setup a worker dyno on heroku and use their "Heroku Scheduler" to setup a background task.  It's incredibly easy and well documented.  You would make a rake task in your lib/tasks folder and then call it via the heroku scheduler using their api on your account dash. Docs can be found here:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#defining-tasks